# Exclude models with criteria from Scout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout

My `User` model has a nullable column `name`. I never want to import users, that have no name.

I tried

```php
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    if (!$this->name) {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];
    }
}
```

but this has no effect to the import or adding.

Answer (score 0):

This function help to determine if the model should be searchable.

```
public function shouldBeSearchable(): bool
{
    return (bool) $this->name;
}
```